# Scrollbar horizontal PaginateDatatable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I would like to create a view that scrolls both vertically and horizontally. I tried but it doesn't work. I don't know how to arrange the layout. I have a text as the title and the datagrid. When I have many columns I would like to scroll the view horizontally.  I could also change the listview ... the important thing is that it can scroll vertically and horizontally
Thanks to all who want to help me

```
 return Container(
  
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
      child: ListView(
       
        children: [
          Text('Users List', style: CustomLabels.h1),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Scrollbar(
            controller: _firstController,
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            child: PaginatedDataTable(
               
               sortAscending: praticheProvider.ascending,
               sortColumnIndex: praticheProvider.sortColumnIndex,
               columns: [......
```

Comment: Can or can’t? Kindly review your question.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean. I can change the layout too. Now I have a listview that doesn't scroll horizontally and I don't see the whole datatable. this is the problem I would like to solve